# Localization for "Home" site (eg https://example.com/de" results in 403 — Forbidden

Tags: craft3, localization, uri

I have set up a multilingual site in Craft CMS and the localization (via url-slug eg. .../de/...) works on all pages. However, on the home site (index.twig) this leads to an error message "403 - Forbidden". What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example: English (default) http://craft-cms-hs.frb.io and German: http://craft-cms-hs.frb.io/de/

[image]

Comment: Use the same setting for both sites. Tick the _home_ checkbox for your Craft CMS (DE) site. If you have set the Base URL for your DE site to something like`@web/de`, the `de` will be added automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Oli but this doesn't work. The Problem is still the same. For the /de version it outputs a 403 _ Forbidden. Here is the example in English (default): http://craft-cms-hs.frb.io/ and the German Version http://craft-cms-hs.frb.io/de/

Comment: I can't see the 403? Is it fixed?

Comment: I have exactly the same Problem. How did you fix it?